# length of binary tree

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

What do we mean by length of binary tree - number of nodes, or height of tree?

Thank you

Comment: I for one never talk about a tree's length but about its depth...

Comment: If the tree was implemented as an array, then _maybe_ I could see length having meaning.  But it isn't used to describe a property of trees in general.

Comment: You might want to ask your professor or teaching assistant what *they* mean.  It would help if you could provide a quote, link or reference so we could see context the phrase appears in.

Comment: Not a term I've heard used for trees.  Definitely needs context.  My first instinct would be they mean "depth", but OTOH "length" may refer to the length of a traversal path through the tree, i.e. number of nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a term I have seen used to describe the properties of a binary tree.  I would guess someone using it would be referring to the depth.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally think of 'length' as the height (depth), not the size (# of nodes) of the tree, but this is quite a contextual question.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, 'length' refers to the number of items in the underlying data structure.
The height of the tree would be its 'depth'

Answer (score 0):

I am going to argue that the n, number of nodes is the "best" answer.

Almost any recursively consistent measure might be argued as a potential answer, e.g. height.   However, size of tree=n, number of nodes is the largest numerical answer.

Height of tree=log n, and the others will all be same or smaller numbers.   So I conclude that node-count "should" be the length of a tree.  It carries the most bits of information of the arguable possibilities.